# How should REST API accept boolean values?

Tags: rest, http, url

Resource `123` has a current configuration state and a default configuration state, and both of these configuration states can be represented by JSON.

A `GET` request to `http://example.com/123/config` will return the current configuration state, and a `GET` request to `http://example.com/123/config?reset=true` will return the default configuration state.

How should an API interpret boolean values?  For instance:

- `http://example.com/123/config?reset=true`
- `http://example.com/123/config?reset=blablabla`
- `http://example.com/123/config?reset=false`
- `http://example.com/123/config?reset=1`
- `http://example.com/123/config?reset=0`
- `http://example.com/123/config?reset=`
- `http://example.com/123/config?reset`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Whichever way you want it to, it's completely up to you as the architect/designer. `true/false` is the most syntactically correct version, make sure that one works and add the other options as sugar if you want.

Comment: Yes, I know it is up to me, but I wish to do so the way most users would expect.  I am thinking that if `reset` is included in the query and is set to any value other than `false` (case insensitive) or `0`, then `reset` will be interpreted as TRUE.  Seem reasonable?  Thanks for your response.

Comment: Most sane users, I would assume, expect the variables of a `boolean`-type parameter to be boolean values, e.g. `true` or `false`. Anything else **should**, at least in the beginning, result in a `HTTP 400: Bad Request` response.

Don't waste your time building an intricate state-machine that can accept 0/1, t/f or whatever else, the chances it will be actually used are practically non-existant. And even if someone requests it, you should instead take the stance to have the user conform to a proper boolean-pattern. Things like this should be standardized.

Comment: Well, we should cater to sane users!  I was originally basing my implementation on how HTML attributes such as `selected` need any value to be considered true.

Comment: I don't think booleans are always fine: https://ariya.io/2011/08/hall-of-api-shame-boolean-trap

Answer (score 14):

### True and false

The `true` and `false` literals are just fine to represent boolean values. They are quite descriptive and, if your API supports JSON, `true` and `false` are definitively the obvious choices.

### Enumerations

In a few situations, however, you may want to avoid boolean values because they cannot be expanded. You may want to consider *enumerations* instead.

It may be a poor comparison but it might help you to get the main idea of this approach: have a look at CSS properties such as [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) or [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility). They allow expandable values instead of only `true` or `false`. So new values can be easily added without changing the property names.

So, for the situation described in your question, to retrieve the default state of a resource, I would support a query parameter such as `status`, that could have values such as `default` and `current`.

The following would return the *default* state of the resource:

```js
GET /config?status=default HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: application/json
```

And the following would return the *current* state of the resource:

```js
GET /config?status=current HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Accept: application/json
```

If no query parameter is provided, you could that the client wants the *current* state of the resource.

---

If you need to restore the resource state to its *default* state, consider using `PUT`, sending the new representation of the resource in the request payload. Something like:

```js
PUT /config/status HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Content-Type: application/json

{ 
  "value": "default" 
}
```

Comment: I am not using `GET` to modify a state.  I am using `GET` to get the current or the default resource state.  If the user gets the default state, they can later use `PUT` to save it.

Comment: @user1032531 Sorry, I misunderstood your question. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Ah, much better answer!  A different approach I didn't consider.  Instead of saying true/false to return a given state, specify the desired state.  Let me think it over.  You think this is a better approach?  Thanks!

Comment: @user1032531 I have been using this approach for a while and I do like it. I like literal values such as `current` and `default`. And this approach especially useful when the state can be expanded (`boolean` values do not give you such flexibility).

Comment: You make a good argument.  I should have phrased the question "should literal values or boolean values be uses...."

Comment: @user1032531 It's a poor comparison but I think it will help you to get the main idea of this approach: have a look at CSS properties like `overflow` or `hidden`. They allow expandable values instead of only `true` or `false`. New values can be easily added without changing the property names.

Comment: I don't think booleans should be the automatic choice and I try to see if there's a more natural and explicit solution that I may have missed instead of just assuming an on / off value is best represented by a boolean: [sometimes booleans are a bad choice](https://ariya.io/2011/08/hall-of-api-shame-boolean-trap). For instance, instead of `verbose=true` it may be better (and more future proof) to have `verbosity=1`. And instead of `messages=true` it is more explicit to have `flags="MESSAGES_ON"` and therefore also `flags="MESSAGES_OFF"`.